# Why does Lightroom Classic complain when no My Pictures folder exists during Import?

Tags: lightroom

After cleanup up empty directories from my system, I found a curious behavior in Adobe Lightroom Classic 10.1. When opening the Import dialog, the following dialog shows up despite having never imported, exported or saved anything in the deleted folder and the Import dialog showing a different valid folder of images. In other words, Lightroom Classic opens the Import dialog, shows the content of the folder about to be imported but complains that a folder which was never used is not available! In all cases, Import is set to *Add* in-place and never to move or copy images.

[image]

Comment: What is the name of the folder that is not showing between the two quotation marks? What are the missing words in the title?

Comment: Strange that there's no name! My guess is that its "My Pictures" because I got rid of a number of empty folders, mostly starting with "My" which are on the system by default but are a very poor way of organizing stuff!

Comment: Have you tried creating another "My Pictures" folder in the appropriate path to see if that fixes it?

Comment: Apparently, it's just *Pictures* in the %USERPROFILE% directory, *My Pictures* points to *Pictures* normally, so creating the new folder, even though it is empty and nothing is written into it by Lightroom Classic, makes the error go away! What is going on there?

Comment: Most OSes hate having defined system folders thrown away. I'm surprised it let you discard it. The path will be defined in some app variable squirrelled away in the Registry somewhere.